# When submitting a form for JavaScript validation what does the return before the function call do?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
```

Why must there be a `return` before `validateForm()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `return`, Javascript will call `validateForm` but will throw away the return value.

If `onsubmit` returns `false` the form won't be submitted.

Comment: But can also be passed with a perfectly-valid event handler, depending on how the validate function was written.

Answer (score 1):

The default submit action of the `<form>` can be stopped if the `onsubmit` function returns `false`.

The value of the `onsubmit` attribute is treated like a function body, so the `return` is needed so that the form isn't submitted if it's not valid.

Comment: Not exactly.  There's no difference between returning false and returning the return value of another function, which happens to be false.

It's more a matter of the inline eval() of the code.

Comment: @Norguard: What are you trying to say?  I don't follow.

Comment: Sorry, my brain is melting.
What I had intended to say is that the return-value of the onclick function would still submit the form if the validate function weren't written to expressly return 'false', and that there are other ways of achieving that value.    The statement that you can assume a "validate" function that you're looking at in somebody else's code would be returning false in this case is 100% true -- but for somebody who's just writing their first, they might expect to just throw alerts, or return anything false-ish, rather than exactly false.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what's happening in that inline handler is this:

```
<button id="submit-button" type="submit" onclick="return validate()"></button>

var button = document.getElementById("submit-button");

button.onclick; // function () { return validate(); }
```

Versus:

```
<button id="submit-button" type="submit" onclick="validate(event)"></button>

var button = document.getElementById("submit-button");

button.onclick; // equals function (event) { validate(event); }
```